# HTTP headers from some clients have characters randomly replaced

Tags: http-headers

Doing web traffic and log analysis, but there are a lot of malformed headers being passed from clients. These have characters transposed or replaced with "x"'s.

Does anyone know where they come from or why?
Is this some kind of attempt at security, or something more nefarious?

Examples:

```
xroxy-connection: Keep-Alive
cneoction: close
nncoection: close
ocpry-connection: Keep-Alive
pxyro-connection: close
proxy-~~~~~~~~~~: ~~~~~~~~~~
x-xorwarded-for: 000.00.00.000
Referer: http://www.example.xom/nxws/article/2009-1x-21/?cid=4xxx00x2-0x60x3x0
```

Comment: In what context is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the **Missed Cneonctions** section of [Fun With HTTP Headers](http://www.nextthing.org/archives/2005/08/07/fun-with-http-headers).  The author thinks:

> I now believe this is something done
>   by a hackish hardware load balancer
>   trying to “remove” the connection
>   close header when proxying for an
>   internal server. That way, the
>   connection can be held open and images
>   can be transmitted through the same
>   TCP connection, while the backend web
>   server doesn’t need to be modified at
>   all.

Answer (score 1):

[A Google search for "xroxy-connection"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22xroxy-connection%22) turns up a security advisory on [Kerio Winroute Firewall](http://seclists.org/bugtraq/2003/Nov/220) which replaces the first character in a header with an X for some reason.

The letter transposition is probably a similar proxying issue, if I had to take a guess.