# HTTP Header - ntCoent-Length

Tags: http, http-headers

I get the following HTTP response headers in a particular response.  All looks okay.  However I have noticed that the content-length appears twice...

Content-Length: 2424
ntCoent-Length: 2424

Is there a particular reason why the content-length is returned a second time as ntCoent-Length?

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 26 May 2010 09:38:19 GMT
Server: Apache
P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR CURa ADMa TA1a OUR BUS IND UNI COM NAV INT"
Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1, unicode-1-1;q=0.8
Expires: Sun, 15 Jul 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Language: en
ntCoent-Length: 2424
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 2424
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The comments in https://basildoncoder.com/blog/turbocharging-net-webservice-clients.html say the jumbled ntCoent-Length header contains the uncompressed size of the response.

You should see the Content-Length is smaller than ntCoent-Length in cases where Content-Encoding:gzip or similar

Comment: Thats is what I thought it was used for.  Good to get it clarified. Is this common practice?

Comment: I cant find this documented in any RFC, though it shows in all response headers.

Comment: It seems to be a trick hardware load balancers use to allow it to "discard" the header [without having to recalculate the TCP and IP checksum of the packet](http://www.nextthing.org/archives/2005/08/07/fun-with-http-headers#comment-1595) by [shuffling the characters in the header name](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX108955) so someone doesn't write support for this "new header".

Comment: Link seems to be dead now

Comment: The link is now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, [HTTP headers from some clients have characters randomly replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628593/http-headers-from-some-clients-have-characters-randomly-replaced) gives other examples of letter transposition in http headers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a munged ntCoent-Length header without the correct version being present. The lack of a valid Content-Length is causing Mule ESB to throw an error out of the HTTP connector. Very annoying. I'm hoping our network team can control this with some Netscaler configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Citrix ADC/NetScaler, it invalidates the HTTP header Content-Length when a rewrite is used in a response. For more info, check https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX211605